# How to create a new thread

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio

I'm new in programming so this may not sound very well, butt, after I did some research in understood that I can create a new thread so multiple blocks of codes can run i parallel. Can someone explain me how can I create a new thread. I'm using Visual studio on Windows.

Comment: Are you coding in `C` not `C++`? And which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2012 and I'm coding in C.

Comment: [This site](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) answers all the questions you didn't ask.

Comment: Are you plan to create/use thread with [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or you want to use [pthread API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)? You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the pthread_create function we can create the thread.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<pthread.h>
```

pthread_t tid;
       pthread_t tid1;
    void *thrd(void *a)
     {
        printf("thread created\n");

```
    printf("%u\n",(unsigned int )tid);
  }
    void *thrd1(void *a)
 {
    printf("second thread created\n");
    printf("%u\n",(unsigned int)tid1);
   }

   main()
   {

    int a=pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thrd,NULL);
    int b=pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thrd1,NULL);
    sleep(1);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try that code

```
       #include<stdio.h>
       #include<pthread.h>

       void *hello(void *arg)
       {
         printf("thread id=%u\n",(unsigned)pthread_self());
        printf("hello welocme Thread created \n");
       }

      main()
     {
       pthread_t tid;

        tid=pthread_create(&tid,NULL,hello,NULL);


    }
```

compile:

cc filename.c -pthread